# Expected Component class, got [object Object] - React-Native

Tags: react-native, create-react-app

I have encountered this problem on "Expected a Component class, Got [object Object]". I have lookup all the related problems on Stack, I have followed most of them by Capitalising my objects but the same errors occurred. Some great pointers would be appreciated.

this is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from "./Login";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <Login />
   );
  }
 }
```

and my Login.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import{
 StyleSheet,
 View,
 Text,
 Image,
 touchableOpacity,
 TextInput,
 KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends React.Component{
 render(){
  return(
   <KeyboardAvoidingView
     behavior="padding"
     style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <TextInput
          underlineColor="transparent"
          placeholder="Email"
          returnKeyType="next"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onSubmitEditing={()=> this.passwordInput.focus()}
          style={styles.input}/>
        <TextInput
          underlineColor="transparent"
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry
          returnKeyType="go"
          ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
          style={styles.input}/>
          <touchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.textButton}>Login</Text>
          </touchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
   }
  }
```

It returns an error of Expected a component class, got [object Object]

Thanks in advance. It is either I'm too blind to see my mistake or I did it completely wrong.

Comment: `touchableOpacity` is lowercased in `Login`...

Comment: @AndrewLi that resolved the issue Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug, I just need to capitalize my components. `touchableOpacity` --> `TouchableOpacity`
Thanks to Andrew Li